# Issues with filtering Tweepy streams

Tags: python, filter, twitter, stream, tweepy

I am working on a project where my code needs to react when a Twitter user tweets @foo using #bar. I have followed the tutorial here https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html and I have my code partially working. The issue is that it works when I tweet "@foo I like #bar" but I get no response when I tweet "@foo #bar" (see my code below). Has anyone else had this issue?

```
import tweepy
import threading
import random
import board
import neopixel
import random
import colorsys
import numpy as np
import time
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import busio
import adafruit_pca9685
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
hat = adafruit_pca9685.PCA9685(i2c)

# Set channels to the number of servo channels on your kit.
# 8 for FeatherWing, 16 for Shield/HAT/Bonnet.
kit = ServoKit(channels=16, frequency=50)

pixel_pin = board.D18
num_pixels = 300
ORDER = neopixel.GRB

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(
    pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.2, auto_write=False, pixel_order=ORDER
)



access_token = "1345547423154888706-VibtuSn31Aeu4e827GKaZmEnCVxsj7"
access_token_secret = "VfciVdPUW5STkVePYewyMTEWYo5rXhgOOHqyLFW5vk7tU"
consumer_key = "jrJFgRGHTg8MH8gcwgUMiL9lO"
consumer_secret = "UXOCkkEj1Y2eDzqzfKtqnC8K0IvsrdtzBe2sprIwDkqrLTHQes"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="@PerotMuseum", rpp=100).items():
#     inCaps = tweet.text.upper()
#     if not "RT " in inCaps:
#         if "#FOSSILFRIDAY" in inCaps:
#             print(tweet.user.name+":")
#             print(tweet.text.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict'))
#             #print("\n")
#
class Listener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Listener,self).__init__()
    def on_status(self, status):
        inCaps = status.text.upper()
        if not "RT " in inCaps:
            print("========== "+status.user.name+" ==========")
            print(status.text+"\n")
            t_end = time.time() + 12
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=marquee, args=(10, pickColor(), t_end,))
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(t_end,))
            # t2 = threading.Thread(target=wave, args=())

            t1.start()
            t2.start()


            t1.join()
            t2.join()
            motorDefault()
            detachServos()
            pixels.fill((0,0,0))
            pixels.show()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)
        return False

def SMOOTHERSTEP(x):
    # return((x) * (x) * (x) * ((x) * ((x) * 6 - 15) + 10))
    return np.sin(x * 3.1415 / 2);

def interp(start, stop, t, totsteps):
    v = t / totsteps
    v = SMOOTHERSTEP(v)
    val = (start * v) + (stop * (1 - v))
    # print (val)
    return val

def pickColor():
    h = random.random()
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, 1, 1)
    color = np.multiply(color, 255)
    color = np.floor(color).astype(int)
    return(color)

def loop(t_end):
    steps = 130
    step = 0.0
    steps = steps/4
    while time.time() < t_end:
        # marquee(10, color, int(step))
        if step < steps:
            i = step
            kit.servo[0].angle = interp(130, 95, i, steps)
            kit.servo[1].angle = interp(180, 30, i, steps)
            kit.servo[2].angle = interp(110, 140, i, steps)
            kit.servo[3].angle = interp(120, 90, i, steps)
            step+=1
        elif step < steps * 2:
            i = step - steps
            kit.servo[0].angle = interp(95, 130, i, steps)
            kit.servo[1].angle  = interp(30, 180, i, steps)
            kit.servo[2].angle = interp(140, 110, i, steps)
            kit.servo[3].angle = interp(90, 120, i, steps)
            step+=1
        elif step < steps * 3:
            i = step - steps * 2
            kit.servo[0].angle = interp(130, 95, i, steps)
            kit.servo[1].angle = interp(60, 30, i, steps)
            kit.servo[2].angle = interp(110, 140, i, steps)
            kit.servo[3].angle = interp(60, 90, i, steps)
            step+=1
        elif step < steps * 4:
            i = step - steps * 3
            kit.servo[0].angle = interp(95, 130, i, steps)
            kit.servo[1].angle  = interp(30, 60, i, steps)
            kit.servo[2].angle = interp(140, 110, i, steps)
            kit.servo[3].angle = interp(90, 60, i, steps)
            step+=1
        else:
            step = 0

def marquee(width, color, t_end):
    t = 0
    while time.time() < t_end:
        i = (t%width)
        while i < num_pixels:
            for x in range(int(width/2)):
                pixels[int(i-x)] = color
            i+=width
        pixels.show()
        pixels.fill((0,0,0))
        t+=1
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))
    pixels.show()
# def marquee(width, color, step):
#     for i in range(num_pixels):
#         if(i % width < width/2):
#             if(i + step < num_pixels):
#                 pixels[i+step] = color
#             else:
#                 pixels[i+step-num_pixels] = color
#     pixels.show()
#     pixels.fill((0,0,0))
def wave():
    kit.servo[1].angle = 180#30 right arm
    time.sleep(2)
    kit.servo[1].angle = 160#30 right arm
    time.sleep(.25)
    kit.servo[1].angle = 180#30 right arm
    time.sleep(.25)
    kit.servo[1].angle = 160#30 right arm
    time.sleep(.25)
    kit.servo[1].angle = 180#30 right arm
    time.sleep(.25)
    kit.servo[1].angle = 30#30 right arm

def detachServos():
    for i in range(16):
        channel = hat.channels.__getitem__(i)
        channel.duty_cycle = 0
def motorDefault():
    kit.servo[0].angle = 100#90 skull
    kit.servo[1].angle = 30#30 right arm
    kit.servo[2].angle = 140#150 left arm
    kit.servo[3].angle = 90#90 head
    time.sleep(.5)


try:
    marquee(10, pickColor(), time.time() + 3)
    myStreamListener = Listener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(track=['@Foo', '#Bar'], languages=['en'])
except:
    motorDefault()
    detachServos()
    print("something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. By filtering only English results it was excluding tweets that include only hashtags and handles. I assume this is because hashtags and handles are excluded in language calculations because they can be in any language and not necessarily reflect the language of the tweet itself.

so the solution was changing this:

```
myStream.filter(track=['@Foo', '#Bar'], languages=['en'])
```

to this:

```
myStream.filter(track=['@Foo', '#Bar'])
```